# Aggressive downvoting

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason

Over the past few months, I've noticed Stack Overflow users have been down-voting very aggressively. Every time I see the feeds, there are questions that beginners (new users) or intermediate users post, are downvoted without any comments or reasons (closed as duplicate, etc.).

I agree sometimes the questions are lame or have been addressed elsewhere on the forum. But don't people deserve to know WHY at least? They might be disappointed otherwise. 
Forgive me if I missed out anything or was incorrect with any terms. Just a thought.

Edit: 
I'm not talking about a question which I posted and got downvoted for (before this one). This is embarrassing. LOL. I did not know about the hover on the downvote icon to know the reason. I was just generally expressing on how it could make some users feel down or something like that. The answer below gave me a good suggestion to take a trip first. I haven't done it yet. I only browse around for answers (upvote and comment if required) or to check for any open questions that I might help with. Thanks all.

Comment: Sigh, not again.  Just hover your mouse over the downvote button to see the reason.  Pick from "no research", "unclear" and "not useful".  The close dialog can only express "unclear" and research apparently isn't needed anymore so it just means "not useful".  There are a *lot* of useless questions lately, the kind that made SO lose its favored Google ranking.  They are coming in too fast to keep up with.

Comment: I would actually love to see people down-vote poor Q&As even *more* aggressively. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753788) for instance. 3 close votes, but only 1 down-vote (mine).

Comment: Must not rant about dups.  Must not rant about dups.  Must not rant about dups. Must not rant about dups.   Must not rant about dups.

Comment: Sod it.  ONE SET OF BAD QUESTIONS IS FROM POSTERS WHO DON'T SEACH FOR DUPS BEFORE POSTING!

Comment: hmmmmm so we're january 3rd and that sugestion got asked what..... 4 times ALREADY?... sigh

Comment: Oh and to give you a reason.... I could say -1 for dupe.... or, as will mosty likely happen "-1 because unicorns are fluffy"

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow expects from newcomers to (at least) go through the very elegant, well designed, helpful and descriptive [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

You don't want to Google a question, and get reference to poorly asked question or answer in Stack Overflow. We *do* close questions that don't meet the very minimum standards and the OP will surely know why his question was closed and downvoted because of the dialog he'll see immediately.

Downvotes aren't bad, they are there to give you an indication about something wrong that you're doing, downvoted users should learn from downvotes and target for better posts.

Comment: Downvotes are really directed at inbound readers, not the author; they signal "this isn't likely to have the information you're looking for".

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I disagree with your view.  How can a question that hasn't received any answers or comments be deemed as not likely to have the information an inbound reader is looking for?  Presumably if someone has found the question through a search and then gone to read that question they would be interested in finding an answer.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion - From a question author's perspective downvotes are bad if you don't know why you've been downvoted.  I've had a question downvoted today and I have no idea why.  I've just reviewed the tour and my question 1) is a question not a discussion, 2) is about a specifc coding problem, 3) I have done research (Google & SO) but after reviewing numerous posts and articles by various autors I can't find a definitive answer to my question, 4) I have used appropriate tags.  Nonetheless my question was downvoted with no explanation.  Not at all helpful.

Comment: "... elsewhere on the forum ..." [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).